# OpenMP odd behaviour with SIMD linear and parallel for linear directives

Tags: c++, openmp, simd

I am learning how to use OpenMP with C++ using GNU C compiler 6.2.1 and I tested the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <iostream>

int b=10;

int main()
{
    int array[8];
    std::cout << "Test with #pragma omp simd linear:\n";
    #pragma omp simd linear(b)
    for (int n=0;n<8;++n) array[n]=b;

    for (int n=0;n<8;++n) printf("Iteration %d: %d\n", n, array[n]);

    std::cout << "Test with #pragma omp parallel for linear:\n";
    #pragma omp parallel for linear(b)
    for (int n=0;n<8;++n) array[n]=b;

    for (int n=0;n<8;++n) printf("Iteration %d: %d\n", n, array[n]);
}
```

In both cases I expected a list of numbers going from 10 to 17, however, this was not the case. The `#pragma omp simd linear(b)` is outright ignored, printing only 10 for each value in `array`. For `#pragma omp parallel for linear(b)` the program outputs `10,10,12,12,14,14,16,16`.

I compile the file using `g++ -fopenmp -Wall main.cpp -o main.o`. How can I fix this?

EDIT: Reading the specification more carefully I found that the `linear` clausule overwrites the initial value with the last value obtained (i.e. if we start with `b=10` after the first cycle we have `b=17`).
However, the program runs correctly if I add `schedule(dynamic)` to the parallel for cycles. Why would I have to specify that parameter in order to have a correct execution?

Comment: This is very interesting. This is reproducible with GCC5.4.0 except GCC's openmp does not accept `linear` clause without `simd` clause (the second half of the test code won't compile with GCC). To get b to change on GCC I use `#pragma omp parallel for simd linear(b)` but still, within each thread, the b is a fixed value. You can file a bug report and ask GCC team about it, or to other compiler developer groups.

Answer (score 3):

The [OpenMP specification](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.1/openmpsu116.html#x151-1710002.21.4.6) says:

> The `linear` clause declares one or more list items to be private and to
> have a linear relationship with respect to the iteration space of a
> loop associated with the construct on which the clause appears.

This is an **information only** to the compiler to indicate the linear behavior of a variable in a loop, but in your code `b` is not increased at all. That is the reason you always get `10` in the first loop. So, the strange results obtained is not the compiler's fault. To correct it you have to use
`array[n]=b++;`

On the other hand, for `#pragma omp parallel for linear(b)` loop, OpenMP calculates the starting `b` value for each thread (based on the linear relationship), but this value is still not increased in a given thread. So, depending on the number of threads used you will see different number of "steps".

In the case of `schedule(dynamic)` clause, the `chunk_size` is `1`, so each loop cycle runs in a different thread. In this case the initial `b` value is always calculated by OpenMP, so you get correct values only.